# Put the data from sqlite into hashmap in list form

Tags: android, sqlite, list, hashmap

```
public class ABC extends ListActivity {
static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abc_list);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            list,
            R.layout.abc_list_row,
            new String[] {"AAA","BBB","CCC"},
            new int[] {R.id.aa,R.id.bb, R.id.cc,}
            );

    add();
    setListAdapter(adapter);  
}

   private void add() {        

    DatabaseA databaseHelper = new DatabaseA(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c= db.rawQuery("select * from data", null);
    HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();  

    while(c.moveToNext()){
        Log.d("Debug", c.getString(2));
        temp.put("AAA", c.getString(1));
        temp.put("BBB", c.getString(2));
        temp.put("CCC", c.getString(3));
        list.add(temp);
    } 

    c.close();
    db.close();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : temp.entrySet()) {
        String xx= entry.getKey();
        String yy = entry.getValue();
        Log.d("data", xx+" : "+yy);
    }
}
```

My Logcat:

```
 D/Debug(657): New york
 D/Debug(657): New moon
 D/data(657): AAA : Aug 20, 2012 3:57:02 PM
 D/data(657): BBB : New moon
 D/data(657): CCC : Title
```

My problem is it always left out the first data from sqlite in this list. Besides, everytime i press a button to view this list, it will add those data into this list although they are already exist. I just want to view those data in sqlite in list form. Any way to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your `Map` inside your `while` loop

```
while(c.moveToNext()){
    Map<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();  
    Log.d("Debug", c.getString(2));
    temp.put("AAA", c.getString(1));
    temp.put("BBB", c.getString(2));
    temp.put("CCC", c.getString(3));
    list.add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add cursor moveToFirst() like this:

```
Cursor c= db.rawQuery("select * from data", null);
HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();  
c.moveToFirst();
while(c.moveToNext()){
    Log.d("Debug", c.getString(2));
    temp.put("AAA", c.getString(1));
    temp.put("BBB", c.getString(2));
    temp.put("CCC", c.getString(3));
    list.add(temp);
}
```

And please post the source code when the button is clicked!

Comment: No need to add moveToFirst(), moveToNext() does this automatically for you.

Comment: `public void viewList (View botton) {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClass(this,ABC.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }`

Comment: Anytime you start the ABC activity you call the add() method. In the add() method it will add up since you have define your list as static. If you loose the static, it wont add up I think.